# AS3 How to define an integer then use it in a function

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

I'm making an animation for mobile that moves an image across the screen when the device is tipped. Here's the code I've used to achieve that:

```
var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);
function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    Image1.x -=  event.accelerationX * 300;
    if (Image1.x < 56.75)
    {
        Image1.x = 56.75;
    }
    else if (Image1.x > 1856.75)
    {
        Image1.x = 1856.75;
    }
}
```

I want to be able to turn Accelerometer input on and off when I click different buttons on the menu screen.

What I thought was to have an integer equal to 1 before I click any buttons; so I do (accelerationX*300)*[that integer] and the accelerometer is enabled. Then I click a 'disable' button, that 1 becomes a 0 and the accelerometer is disabled. Then click another button and the integer becomes 1 again.

How do I do this and is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What I thought was to have an integer equal to 1 before I click any buttons;

A `boolean` would be the better choice, but you don't really need an additional variable

To disable the accelerometer in the handler function, simply remove the listener in it:

```
fl_Accelerometer.removeEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);
```

Comment: That looks much simpler. I'm such a noob.

Answer (score 2):

@null is right as usual...

> A boolean would be the better choice, but you don't really need an
>   additional variable

You may declare the

```
var accControl:Boolean = true; // Variables names should start with a lowercase letter
```

Then, you change it as this:

```
accControl = !accControl; // if true => false if false => true
```

Or with an Integer, you may do

```
var accControl:int = 1;
```

then

```
accControl *= -1; // if 1 => -1 if -1 => 1
```

If You have a lot of Buttons a Boolean is perhaps the better choice.

Even null's code is more clean AMO, this may helps someone I hope.

Just an example in flash which contains a CustomButton in the Library:

**tl, dr;**

```
var marginX:int = 20;
var spacerX:int;
var accControl:Boolean = true; // Variables names should start with a lowercase letter
var accControlInt:int = 1; // Variables names should start with a lowercase letter
var buttons:Vector.<SimpleButton> = new Vector.<SimpleButton>();
function addButtonsFromLib():void{
    for(var i:int=0 ; i<10 ; i++){
    buttons.push(new CustomButton);
    addChild(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].name = "customButton_" + (i+1)
    spacerX = buttons[i].width;
    buttons[i].x = marginX + spacerX*i + buttons[i].width*i;
    buttons[i].y = 20;
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClickInt);
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,onClickBool);
    }
}
addButtonsFromLib();
function onClickBool(me:MouseEvent):void{
    accControl = !accControl; // if true => false if false => true
    trace(me.target.name + " cliqued => Boolean value is set to : " + accControl);
}
function onClickInt(me:MouseEvent):void{
    accControlInt *= -1; // if 1 => -1 if -1 => 1
    trace(me.target.name + " cliqued => int value is set to : " + accControlInt);
}
```

Comment: This avoid You to create two methods if You use a Boolean or an integer.
Just chose if You want to use a Boolean or an int.
The trace method is just useful for debugging.
You can forget this @user7083681 !
In place of trace, call another method!
It was just an example!

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var AccControl:int;
AccControl = 1;
{

MenuScreen.ToggleOffAcc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AccOff);
function AccOff(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    AccControl = AccControl + 1;
}

MenuScreen.ToggleOnAcc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AccOn);
function AccOn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    AccControl = AccControl - 1;
    MenuScreen.ToggleOnAcc.visible=false;
}
}

var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);

function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    Street.x -=  ((event.accelerationX * 300)* AccControl);

    if (Street.x < 56.75)
    {
        Street.x = 56.75;
    }
    else if (Street.x > 1856.75)
    {
        Street.x = 1856.75;
    }
}
```